# how to share dictionary on facebook in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, nsdictionary

I am trying to post dictionary to facebook in which image is attached, when user click on the image then should redirect the user to a link. I need to share the dictionary in the format shown in the attached image. If anybody knows that how can I achieve[image]

the attached format then please let me know.

Comment: You can't share a NSDictionary because facebook doesn't know what a dictionary is. But you can read the facebook SDK documentation to see how to share an image with a link and then create a method that post on facebook from your NSDictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code , i also use this code for my app and resolve a issue ..

```
- (void)sendDataOnfacebook {
    [self performPublishAction:^{
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"FASHMOD", @"name",
                                       strFBPostUrl,@"link",
                                       strFBPostTitle, @"message",
                                       strFBPostImageUrl,@"picture",
                                       @"Be a fashion model",@"description",nil];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Shared successfully");
            NSLog(@"status %@ %@  ",result,error);
        }];
    }];
}
```